# Google Sheet: How to ensure a string like "405,270" regarded as string but not number?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The data in my K8 cell is

```
405,270 | 450.00,300.00
```

other data in K column is like

```
270 | 300.00
```

I am trying to use

```
=index(split(K8," | ",0),1)
```

to get the value `405,270` so I can use another split to get value 405. However, the formula above returns 405270 as a number.
How should I improve my formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via REGEXEXTRACT:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(K1,"(.+)?\|")
```

And, if you need it as an array:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(K1:K,"(.+)?\|")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I substitute all "," with another symbol like "@"

So the final formula is like

```
=index(split(index(split(subsitute(K8,",","@")," | ",0),1),"@"),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
=SPLIT(K8; "| ,")
```

[image]